# How to use Sine, Cosine, Tan and Sqrt in Eiffel?

Tags: math, trigonometry, sqrt, eiffel

Coders out there - I suspect that's not more than 10 people worldwide:) - ,

I have a very, very simple question:

How can I compute sin, cos, tan or sqrt with a REAL?

```
a: REAL
b: REAL
...
b := a.power(2)
```

works, but ...

```
a: REAL
b: REAL
...
b := a.sin(2)
b := a.tan(2)
b := a.cos(2)
b := a.sqrt()
```

... does not.

Dear Internet, please don't let me down!

Paul:)

Comment: I don't know Eiffel, but shouldn't you just drop the parameters of `sin` etc.?

Comment: There are a lot more Eiffel users out there, not that many on SO though.

Comment: Eiffel?  I thought that language was dead.  I guess no language ever dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two library classes: `SINGLE_MATH` for `REAL_32` and `DOUBLE_MATH` for `REAL_64`. If you plan to use only one kind of reals, just inherit from one of the classes and use

```
        b := sine (a)
        b := cosine (a)
        b := tangent (a)
        b := sqrt (a)
```

If you want to mix single and double precision reals, you can add once functions like

```
single_math: SINGLE_MATH
    once
        create Result
    end
```

and then use

```
        b := single_math.sine (a)
        b := single_math.cosine (a)
        b := single_math.tangent (a)
        b := single_math.sqrt (a)
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much. It works like a charme. You are great!